# Android Push Notification/Message Concept

Tags: android

can someone explain about how push notification or message in android working? Does it operate within a VPN? How can the server send data to the device if it's not in the same network? 
 Is it possible to make your own push notification/message? 
Please enlightened me :)

Answer (score 0):

Push Notification in Android means, Google Cloud Messaging. First we need to enable google cloud messaging service from google developer console. Then need to create browser key to give from server side.

Now, when user need push, we have to register the device id to the google cloud server and it saved it permanently.

Now when server fires push at that time server request google cloud to send message to registered device id, and using that device id, google sends message to that particular device. So basically, whole things are depends on Device id.

Comment: Hey, can u tell me about how can the server send/push message to device id? Does it use tcp/ip?